# Not able to get url parameter value in a Sharepoint "calulated column"

Tags: sharepoint-2013

I want to get a url parameter value in a calculated column...here is the url

http://xyz/Forms/FormsVJFs/123.xml?OpenIn=Browser&DefaultView=myview&Source=http://xyz/sharepoint/distribution/

I want to get "myview" in my calculated column...Is there a formula for it?

Answer (score 0):

Got it working..

Here is the formula...

=LEFT(RIGHT([URLCOLUMN],LEN([URLCOLUMN])-INT(FIND("DefaultView=",[URLCOLUMN])+11)),INT(FIND("&",RIGHT([Title],LEN([Title])-INT(FIND("DefaultView=",[Title])+11))))-1)